# SQL Server - error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, type-conversion

I am inserting table A to table B. The problematic column looks like `-$25.2`. I first replaced the `$` and tried `insert`. Got this error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

I then checked by

```
SELECT * 
FROM B 
WHERE ISNUMERIC([Col Name]) <> 1
```

and no results were returned.

This is odd. It is supposed to return something.

What should I check next?

I also tried something like

```
CAST(REPLACE([Col Name], '-$', '') AS FLOAT)
```

Comment: Don't use ISNUMERIC().  $, ., ,, -, + all return as a 1 even with no numbers. Try_Parse is better

Comment: @dfundako: `Try_Parse` unfortunately isn't available in SQL Server **2008** ... that's a new feature in **2012** only ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
DECLARE @Text nvarchar(100)

SET @Text = '-$1234.567'
SET @Text = Replace(@Text,'$', '')
Select CONVERT(float, @Text) AS ColumnValue
Select ABS(CONVERT(float, @Text)) AS ColumnValue
```

Comment: `Try_Parse` unfortunately isn't available in SQL Server **2008** ... that's a new feature in **2012** only ...

Comment: Noted, I removed it from the answer.

Comment: Did this answer help @John Hass?

Answer (score -2):

While the 'money' data type isn't great for doing calculations, in this scenario you can use it as an intermediary.

```
declare @a nvarchar(10)

set @a = '-$25.2'

select 
    @a,
    cast(cast(@a as money) as float)
```

Only use this though if your data only goes to a max of 4 decimal places, otherwise you will lose precision in the conversion.